# how i can print same header and footer in all pages in print view of document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, printing

I want to repeat page header and footer in all html pages while taking print. i have try many online solution but i m still unable to fix this issue.
even css position:fixed is also not working for chrome and page-break-after tag is also not working in chrome. if i add position:fixed for header and footer div then it repeat header and footer on every page but contents overlap with footer and header.

Is there any other way to repeat header and footer for all pages in print view with proper page formate.

Comment: Show us some code that what you tried

Comment: show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @You should have your HTML output for header and footer within document you want to print, so just change your "template for it"

Comment: i have an html header and footer withing document & 
its not template issue. i search about this issue . Google chrome doesn't support position:fixed and page break after property due to which we can't  set header and footer in all pages properly. contents overlap with footer and header. . I just want to repeat header and footer in every page of print doc. with proper formate.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try for placing bottom:0 in the css.
Eg:

<div class="divfooter">SomethingOnthePageBottomandHeader</div>

 <style type="text/css">
    @media screen {
        div.divfooter {
            display: none;
        }
    }
    @media print {
        div.divfooter {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: it is not working for chrome i already mention position:fixed in my question.